# Can't preview SSRS 2008 report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to develop some SSRS reports in VS2008 and when I preview them I receive the following error message:

```
Failed to load policy file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\RSPreviewPolicy.config
This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework.  In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LogacySecuirityPolicy configuration switch.  Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information
```

In order to attempt to resolve, I have added the following toe my RSPreviewPolicy.config file

```
<runtime>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

However, I have rebooted my machine and this didn't take care of it.   Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it... I need to add

```
<runtime>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config file not the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\RSPreviewPolicy.config

Once I did that and restarted VS2008 it worked fine